# How to add a ripple effect in Swift & SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit I have a starting button

```
    startButton = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 130, height: 130))
    startButton.name = "startButton"
    startButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    self.addChild(startButton)
```

and around this node I want to add a ring that will expand and come back in again sort of like a rippling effect, so how would I add this effect?

Comment: Just make the radius of the stroke larger with Action?

Answer (score 1):

Because it is in SpriteKit you have a few options, you could create a sprite that is the same shape as your button but only has an outline but no fill. Place this below your button and then when you want to do the ripple effect apply some actions to below image (repeat3times(sequence[scaleUp, fadeOut]))

Or you could take the same stroked image and create an effect in the particle editor, and then apply that particle effect to your button

You can check out my similar solution here [How To Create a Pulse Effect On an SKSpriteNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083360/how-to-create-a-pulse-effect-on-an-skspritenode/43085170#43085170)